# Change VSCode default behaviour of resolving environments for Xonsh

Tags: visual-studio-code, xonsh

I am using Kubuntu 21.10 with VSCode 1.62.3.

I just changed my default shell from bash to [Xonsh](https://xon.sh/).
I click on the VSCode icon from my app menu to open it and it keeps complaining "Resolving Shell Environment fails". (Log in main process is repeating `[main] [error] RequestService#request resolving shell environment failed {}` over and over again until it finally give up).

[VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_resolving-shell-environment-fails) tells me that this is because resolving environments takes too much time (> 10 s).
However I tried source `.bashrc` with `bash`. It is done *instantly*.
There aren't much things besides default setting auto-generated while installing Ubuntu.
Sourcing `.xonshrc` with `xonsh` takes less than 0.1 s too.

I guess it is because VSCode tries to source my `.bashrc` with `xonsh` though `xonsh` is not compatible with `bash`.
However I do not know how to do to configure VSCode, for example change the way it resolve environment to solve this.
(I am not sure if I shall raise an issue at [VSCode's github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).)

I know I can launch VSCode from terminal with `code .`. It works, yet I'd just rather launch VSCode from the menu instead.